# ReferenceError undefined on defined function

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a function defined in my app.component.ts file defined as as such

```
export class AppComponent {

    ....

    onRowSelected(record:any) {
       this.selectedRecord = record;
    }

   ....
}
```

I use the function in the app.component.html file as a callback function when a table row is selected

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records">
    <div onclick="onRowSelected(record)">
        <!-- Create a checkbox for each row -->
        <td>
            <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
        </td>
        <!-- For each entry in the config, create a cell -->
        <td *ngFor="let column of config.columns" 
         ....
        </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

I don't understand why I am getting

```
VM11199 Uncaught ReferenceError: onRowSelected is not defined
```

when the function is clearly defined in my component. Any insights?

Comment: you should use `(click)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onclick` is a "vanilla" (regular) JavaScript binding. The function executed will be `window.onRowSelected`. Since it doesn't exist, you get the error.

The correct way for binding JavaScript events in Angular2 is `(nameOfTheEvent)="codeToBeExecuted"`. This way, the functions at the `@Component` will be available.

This way, since you are trying to bind the click event, for angular, the correct is `(click)`.

So this:

```
<div onclick="onRowSelected(record)">
```

Should become:

```
<div (click)="onRowSelected(record)">
```